# intersect arrays sort by array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays I am intersecting them to get one array. But I want to sort by array.

Example:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9);
$array2 = array(2, 8, 5);
$array3 = array_intersect ($array1, $array2);
print_r($array3);
```

Which results

```
Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 5 [4] => 8 )
```

But I need sort by $array2

```
Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 8 [4] => 5 )
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: `$array3 = array_intersect ($array2, $array1);`? Or do you need the keys from $array1 and the order of values from $array2, in which case you'll need to do this in two steps to sort after the array_intersect()

Comment: Just I need values. No need of keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Reverse the array_intersect by array2 and array1

```
$array1 = array(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9);
$array2 = array(2, 8, 5);
$array3 = array_intersect ($array2, $array1);
print_r($array3);
```

Now you can get the result as

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 8 [2] => 5 )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array3 = array_intersect ($array2,$array1);

print_r($array3);

Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 8 [2] => 5 )
```